# Setting the value of a textbox and retrieving it later on

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I got several aspx textboxes and asign their text value in my page int the on load function
The text is read out of a database.

Default.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="suggestion" CssClass="inputBoxField" runat="server" Text="" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="10" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Default.aspv.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
 . . . . 
    suggestion.Text = suggestionValue
End Sub
```

Now I got a button click event and want to retrieve the value of the textbox.

```
Protected Sub save_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    Dim suggestionValue As String = suggestion.Text
 ......
End Sub
```

The problem I am facing is that the suggestionValue  will be the text I set in the page on load function no matter if the user changed the actual text of the textbox in the meantime. Do I have to call some kind of update function?

Answer (score 1):

Only change the text of the text if the page is not posting back

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
    If not Me.IsPostBack then
      suggestion.Text = suggestionValue
    End If
End Sub
```